# How to extract a dataframe from another dataframe in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I was working with a consolidated df and use `summarise(n = count(var))` to understand about the duplicates. Then I obtained this object call `x`:

```
      n.x         n.freq
1 001121011522      1
2 001121711014      1
3 001121711015      1
4 001121711722      1
5 001121711723      1
6 001131811722      1
```

I know `n.freq` goes from 1 to 6 so i want to only grab the ones which are higher or equal to 2:

```
y <- x %>% filter(n$freq >= 2)
```

But I got this:

```
Error: Column `n` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

So I checked its structure and got this:

```
    > str(x)
'data.frame':   485843 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ n:'data.frame':  485843 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x   : Factor w/ 485843 levels "001121011522",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ freq: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

So it looks there is a df inside another one as I can understand. I want to know how to extract the second (inner one) df to use it.

[UPDATE]: using `dput(head(x, 20))` I got:

```
"ABC253478", "ABC983659", "ABC654911", "ABC882310", 
..... # there were at least 100 rows of results
"ABC665892", "ABC441276", "ABC906138", "ABC679967"
), class = "factor"), freq = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It looks like you typed `n$freq` rather than `n.freq`. A typo?

Comment: try - `x %>% filter(n.freq >= 2)`

Comment: Tried it before `y <- x %>% filter(n.freq >= 2)` but I get the same result.

Comment: Please share output of `dput(head(x, 20))` at the end of your question.

Comment: I have updated as you asked.

Comment: The output of `dput` is useless to us unless you provide the whole thing. The point is that we need to be able to copy and paste it into R ourselves to be able to run it independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has *got* to be something amuck with that data ... but let's see if I can try to reproduce is sufficiently. (Up front: not perfectly, but we don't have enough information yet to be able to improve this much.)

Some sample data, manually written to mock what I think your missing rows are:

```
x <- structure(
  list(n = structure(
    list(x = structure(c(3L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 5L),
                       .Label = c("112916", "116806", "118489", "146802", "154999",
                                  "157333", "170238", "183345", "194348", "194384"),
                       class = "factor"),
         freq = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L) ) ),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L)
)
str(x)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ n:'data.frame':    10 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ x   : Factor w/ 10 levels "112916","116806",..: 3 7 6 2 10 9 1 8 4 5
#   ..$ freq: int  2 1 3 1 2 3 3 1 2 1
```

This does not replicate your error:

```
str( x %>% filter(n$freq >= 2) )
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ n:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ x   : Factor w/ 10 levels "112916","116806",..: 3 6 10 9 1 4
#   ..$ freq: int  2 3 2 3 3 2
```

Perhaps this will work for you instead?

```
str( subset(x, n$freq >= 2) )
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ n:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ x   : Factor w/ 10 levels "112916","116806",..: 3 6 10 9 1 4
#   ..$ freq: int  2 3 2 3 3 2
```

Unfortunately this might work for you, but has the effect of flattening the database (without intention):

```
str( x[ x$n$freq >= 2, ] )
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ x   : Factor w/ 10 levels "112916","116806",..: 3 6 10 9 1 4
#  $ freq: int  2 3 2 3 3 2
```

It appears that this nested frame is fairly simple to unravel:

```
str( x[[1]] )
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ x   : Factor w/ 10 levels "112916","116806",..: 3 7 6 2 10 9 1 8 4 5
#  $ freq: int  2 1 3 1 2 3 3 1 2 1
```

So let's try to replace the nested frame with a "normal" one:

```
xflat <- x[[1]]
str( filter(xflat, freq >= 2) )
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ x   : Factor w/ 10 levels "112916","116806",..: 3 6 10 9 1 4
#  $ freq: int  2 3 2 3 3 2
str( subset(xflat, freq >= 2) )
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ x   : Factor w/ 10 levels "112916","116806",..: 3 6 10 9 1 4
#  $ freq: int  2 3 2 3 3 2
str( xflat[ xflat$freq >= 2, ] )
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ x   : Factor w/ 10 levels "112916","116806",..: 3 6 10 9 1 4
#  $ freq: int  2 3 2 3 3 2
```